# Is there any method to put multiple error types into one objects by @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

This is my first time to raised out question in the stackoverflow. I would like to ask whether there is a method to throw back multiple error types at the same time into one object to users by @ExceptionHandler?

For example, the following requirements needed to meet when user request the service

```
(1) accountNo : required
(2) userDecision : @Pattern(regex="^[1|2]$")
```

However, the user has omitted the accountNo (MissingServletRequestParameterException) and enter userDecision as 3 (ContraintViolationException). Then is it possible for me to throw back a Json Object like

```
 [
    {
        "error1":"your accnoutNo is empty",
        "error2":"your decision is wrong"
    }
]
```

to user at the same time?

Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a custom Validator (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) and in the validate method reject the values.

After that you can implement a ExceptionHandler(extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler) with the @ControllerAdvice Annotation for this Validator where you handle the ValidationExceptions.

Have a look a this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53726774/10664009 maybe it helps